# C# - Sockets: Creating a server and client

Tags: c#, sockets

So I've been looking at many guides, but most of them are outdated and don't work.
This is what I want to achieve, can someone point me in the right direction with some code or new guides?

I want my client to establish a **secure** connection with the server. When a secure connection is established, the client will send a ID to the server. The server will look up the relevant data from the database for the ID and send back the results.

So basically what I want to learn is:

- Setting up a multi-threaded server
- Connecting a database to the server
- Building a secure connection between the client and server(I want to verify that the server is communicating with my client program, not a hacker or something)
- Setting up the client side, so that the client can request data when ever it is required

Thanks, apologies for my newbie-ness.

Comment: Any reason you mentioning sockets here? is it just for learning purpose? from your example it doesnt seem like you need web sockets at all

Comment: First, you should try at least on your own. Secure is a very broad keyword! Nothing in this world can be guaranteed to be secure! You should check how to develop secure C# application. And, I'm voting to close this question as too broad!

Comment: So can it be done without sockets? @Ateik

Comment: Sorry, I just want to verify whether the server is speaking to an actual client. @Am_I_Helpful

Comment: @DininduPerera I've added an answer to acheive your task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple to create such thing,

Start your visual studio and create a new ASP.NET project,select MVC template. Make sure you have the Authentication as "Individual User Accounts" (this option will make enable your website's users to create an account in your website, login and authenticate themselves)

Now of course the connection between the server and the client is not secured, but you shouldnt worry about this for now, you can later purchase SSL certificate and install it in your server.

If you're still learning ASP.NET, you shouldnt really worry about the minor details.

My advise that you take a course from MVA and follow their structured outline to learn:
https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc-8322

Comment: Thanks, but I have a desktop application so this is not going to work.

Comment: It should work, but instead of using ASP.NET MVC template, use ASP.NET WebAPI. 
The client (like android, ios or even desktop application) can still call the server through HTTP. The client will recieve some data (usually json or xml).

Comment: Oh okay. I didn't wanna switch to using sockets as it seemed to be way more complicated. If I can stay with HTTP, it'll be much better.

Comment: Sockets are not complicated if you use "Signalr". But for your needs, web api is more than enough.

Comment: It is really useful, especially if I want to switch to another platform. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a tcp client and server tutorial at Codeproject (including a working sample implementation using C# sockets) as starting point as follows:

[Creating a server/client application using native .NET TCP library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1009151/Creating-a-server-client-application-using-native)

There are numerous working c# sample implementations scattered throughout the internet which are suitable for your intentions, including sourceforge, github and codeproject. Search with keywords that you can pick up in the paper mentioned above.

Note: Yes I know that this should be a comment, but I cannot do it because of my rep. Sorry.

Comment: Thats fine man, the guide was useful.